# Error opening a file with atom from the command line (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables, atom-editor

I just spent some time messing around with my environment variables. I used to be able to type "atom [filename]" into the command prompt and it would open the file in atom (provided I was in the correct directory). Now when I try this, I get the following message:

```
'atom' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I've looked at several threads about this and I have added the path:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\atom\bin
```

to my Path variables (both user and system). Why is it still not working? It has worked in the past and I'm not sure what has changed.

---

1/3/2019 Update:

I can open it if I type `atom.cmd`, but when I removed the `.cmd` extension and it stopped working. I still am not quite sure why it can't be recognized as a command without this extension as my computer did used to be able to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue:

In my system variable PATHEXT, I did not have the extension `cmd`, just `CMD`. These extensions are clearly case sensitive, because adding `cmd` fixed the problem.